# Data not inserting in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing this problem since couple of days where I'm trying to insert the data into mongodb using mongoose but not able to get the data in mongodb. Below is the schema that I have created

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const db = require('../db/db')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const { v4 : uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const validator = require('validator')
// const { stringify } = require('querystring')
const schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new schema({
    ObjId: schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true,
        maxlength: 32
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true,
        validate(value) {
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
                throw new Error ('The Email you have entered is not correct. Please enter the correct Email ID')
            }
        }
    },
    hashed_password : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    about : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    salt : String,
    user_roles: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    history : {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    // timestamps: {
    //     createdAt : '',
    //     updatedAt : {type : Date, default : Date.now()},
    // },
}, {timestamps: true})

// added virtual field

userSchema.virtual('password')
.set((password) =>{
    this.password = password,
    this.salt = uuidv4()
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password)
})
.get(() => {
    return this._password
})


userSchema.methods = {
    encryptPassword : (password) => {
        if(!password) return ''

        try {
            return crypto.createHmac('sha256', this.salt)
                            .update(password)
                            .digest("hex")
        }
        catch(error) {
            if(error) {
                console.log('Found an Error in Line 70 in User.Js', error.message)
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

This is how I'm connecting the db

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config
// const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
//const databaseName = 'ecommerce_db'

mongoose.connect(
    // connectionURL,
    process.env.MONGOURI,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
)
// .then((result) => { console.log('Mongo DataBase Connected', result)})
.then(() => { console.log('Mongo DataBase Connected')})
.catch((err) => {console.log('Mongoose Connection Failed', err)})
```

and this is where I'm saving the data

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const { response } = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


exports.signUp = (req, res) => {
    console.log('[Logging]', req.body)
    // const user = new User({
    //     _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(),
    //     name: req.body.name,
    //     email: req.body.email,
    //     password: req.body.hashed_password
    // })
    const user = new User(req.body)
    user.save((error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error
            })
        }
        res.json({
            user
        })
    })
}
```

I'm getting all the correct input and success messages but still I'm not able to get the data inside mongodb, am I doing something wrong

Comment: can you try returning `response` instead of `user` in `Signup` controller...and tell us what did it return

Comment: It returns this { name: 'Test', email: 'test@test.com', password: 'Test' }
POST /v1/signUp 200 1.422 ms - 66 as a response, but still not able to get it inside mongodb

Comment: then it should insert a recored in DB, I dont see anything wrong

Comment: @RohitAmbre like that I have not done, the dummy code is working with the uri but the same uri will not work with this code, that's what I'm not able to understand

Comment: How are you trying to check the data in MongoDB? And can you share what your MONGOURI looks like(redact the username and password)

Comment: After reading the code carefully, I saw that the parameter while saving was wrong, instead of response it should have been user